# Input/If statement - correct way of writing

Tags: python

I am currently taking part of a beginner Python code challenge and whilst my code runs how it should, the solution is written differently to my program.

As I am just starting out, I was wondering which way is more preferable to write the program,

The solution is:

```
# Prompt user if they want to proceed. Y/N?
should_proceed = input("Do you want to proceed? Y/N ")

# If they want to proceed
if should_proceed.lower() == "y":
    # print out to the screen "SOLD!" to confirm purchase
    # TODO: Gatjer credit card information and process it.
    print("SOLD!")
    # and then decrement the tickets remaining by the number of tickets purchased
    tickets_remaining -= num_tickets
# Otherwise...
else:
    # Thank them by name
    print("Thank you anyways, {}!".format(name))
```

Whereas, I have put:

```
# Prompt user if they want to proceed. Y/N?
proceed = input("Would you like to proceed? Y/N ").upper()

# If they want to proceed
if proceed == "Y":
    # print out to the screen "SOLD!" to confirm purchase
    # TODO: Gatjer credit card information and process it.
    print("SOLD!")
    # and then decrement the tickets remaining by the number of tickets purchased
    tickets_remaining = tickets_remaining - ticket_request
    print(tickets_remaining)
# Otherwise...
elif proceed == "N":
    # Thank them by name
    print("Thank you for your time, {}".format(customer_name))
```

Was it incorrect to call upper() on the input?

Is there any other errors I have done?

Many thanks,

Comment: "Was it incorrect to call upper() on the input?" Both ways are common for allowing case-insensitive input. For more feedback, post your working code at our sister site [CodeReview.SE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ways are fine with one caveat. Because you are specifically checking for both `Y` and `N`, your way is probably better in that case since you would otherwise have to call `upper()` twice:

```
proceed = input("Would you like to proceed? Y/N ")
if proceed.upper() == "Y":
    doSomething()
elif proceed.upper() == "N":
    doSomethingElse()
```

On that enhanced checking, your code is slightly different in that it does *nothing* if the input is neither `Y` nor `N` (the other code treats anything that's not `y` as `n`). In that case, you're probably wise to ensure it *is* one of those values, with something like:

```
proceed = ""
while proceed != "Y" and proceed != "N":
    proceed = input("Would you like to proceed (Y/N)? ").upper()
```

Comment: Thank you for this.. I am currently using `while tickets_remaining > 0:` to check if there are enough tickets for the order, I should use another `while:` to check for the input too?

Comment: @trailrunner89: without seeing the whole code, I can't say for certain. But the input should probably be in its own `while` block since that's the whole intent of it (to simply ensure `y` or `n` is entered). Continuing only while you have remaining tickets is a separate thing.

Answer (score 1):

> Was it incorrect to call upper() on the input?

No, this is a perfectly fine way to allow case-insensitive input. Their solution shows an alternative that works just as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response code-apprentice, I just thought if you called .upper() on the input, then you wouldn't have to call it twice on the elif etc?

Comment: @trailrunner89 you are correct. Often storing the result of a function call is desirable. Especially when you use that value multiple times.